# How to fit a lm model with interaction terms for multiple datasets?

Tags: r

For fitting a lm model in R with all interaction terms included, we use the below method:

```
model1<-lm(resp~var1+var2+var3+var4, dataset)
```

I have multiple dataframes in a list object with different variables however target variable is in column2 for all dataframes. Now, I want to fit a lm model with all possible interaction terms for each dataframe in the list at a time (might be using for loop or using lapply - not sure). is there a way to achieve this in R? 
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this using [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) but people would need to see more of the structure of your list object and the dataframes within them to be able to help further.

Comment: I see no interaction terms in that model.

Comment: They could be built into the variables (say var3 = var1 * var2)